# Recognize object inside a layer in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, image-processing, uibezierpath

How do I recognize an object inside shapeLayer from UIBeizierPath in Swift? Below is the example app PopAGraph. Thanks in advance.

https://vimeo.com/61877513

My code:

```
fileprivate func addNewPathToImage() {
    path.lineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.round
    shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 52/255, green: 152/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
    mainImageView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

My image and shapeLayer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CAShapeLayer his a hitTest() function. In your superview:

```
private func setUpShapeLayer() {

    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(viewTapped))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    [your code to add shapeLayer]

}

internal func viewTapped(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if (shapeLayer.hitTest(p) != nil) {

        [do something here]

    } else if (greenLayer.hitTest(p) != nil) {
}
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, I totally misunderstood what the question was.

The link in the OP is to an app that looks to have some proprietary functions happening. If you wish for similar iOS "out of box" functionality, here's about the best you can do:

(1) Have the user create a CAShapeLayer by panning the outline.

(2) Run a CoreImage filter (CIEdges) on the image to detect all edges.

(3) Find the "best fit" of contiguous (closed with no endpoints) edges where the hitTest() of said edges lay within the CAShapeLayer and highlight it.

I've seen this video a couple of times, and it has me wondering - what if the user traced a shape that cut off the Statue of Liberty head? What would the app do? Cut off the statue head, recognize the full statue, or result in no recognition?

This last observation isn't meant to be opinion, but instead point out that this may be a demo that shows the "best case" features of the app. And if the user does something "less than optimal" or unexpected may in fact give you a better idea of how it accomplishes what it does.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I need to obtain object in a image inside shapeLayer. You can watch video link which is an example already existing app